# Manual code-reformatting exceptions in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, webstorm

While I'm generally in enthusiastic about Webstorm code reformatting, I have some personal preferences that Webstorm doesn't (yet) understand. So I wish I could have a bit more control.

For example, I use RequireJS and AngularJS, both of which have a concept of *module* that takes a list of *dependencies* and a function with corresponding parameters. I like to line them up. E.g., RequireJS:

```
define  (['jquery', 'angular', 'gmaps'],
function ( $      ,  angular ) {
```

And AngularJS:

```
Module.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
                         function ( $scope ,  $element ,  $attrs) {
```

These are exceptions to my usual formatting preferences that don't survive code reformatting. I'd like to have Webstorm work *with* me, rather than against me.

**In order of preference:**

- Can I program this as a reformatting behavior into Webstorm?
- Can I ask Webstorm to ignore spacing for this kind of construct? (Based on function name, perhaps, or some sort of pattern matching on the code?)
- Can I ask Webstorm to ignore spacing altogether?

Comment: The answer is 'no' for all 3 questions:( Please feel free to file requests for these features [to WebStorm issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)

Comment: @lena: Thanks! I will (though not for the next week or two). --- By the way, if you are confident in your response, it's perfectly valid as an Answer (capital A). If you put it up I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is 'no' for all 3 questions:( Please feel free to file requests for these features to [WebStorm issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)